# Monitoring application business logic with zipkin tracking information

Tags: java, zipkin

Actually I have a microservice architecture as follows

[image]

So I have 4 microservices and for every microservice I send a notification to zipkin when starts and finish it's objective.

I have to monitor my product to make sure all requested checkouts will have

- It's payments processed (paid or cancelled)
- The checkout created at database and available for consult
- I have sent a checkout notification e-mail to the customer

zipkin as a tracking system already own all this information cause it keep the checkout track from the very beginning until the end, I'm wondering how I can query at zipkin all checkouts that have been processed by **JAVA REST API** microservice and didn't be processed by at least one of the others (**PAYMENT GATEWAY**, **SALE CREATOR** and **EMAIL NOTIFIER**

How can I query on zipkin which checkouts haven't been processed by all others microservices after **REST API**?

Comment: Zipkin provides a simple API that you could see if that gives what you want, it is mostly used by the UI. For your use case, Zipkin can easily find if the requests are still pending due to latency. It only gives you the total request number for each span, not a combinatorial query for which services are pending. You need to build your own service for that tracking.

Answer (score 0):

we also use use zipkin but can't query with zipkin as elk. we can just click on each services which are display on zipkin and get more info as below image.

[image: after click the service]

Answer (score 0):

Zipkin is not a business transaction tracking system and it should not be used that way because it is not built for this purpose. There are other tools which are built specifically to cater the needs to business operations which you must consider.

P.S. I am a Zipkin contributor.

Comment: thank you for your help, can you mention which tools may I take a look for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to how achieve this with zipkin but yes for the whole problem.

If you have a  transaction that didn't complete it's steps then you probably have two of following issues

**Some microservice failed to deliver the event to the next one and didn't figure it out**

You have to make sure delivery at least once here, using Kafka you have to wait until message get flushed to the server for example

**The destiny microservice received the message and is not processing it**

You have to make sure you application is processing what it's supposed to,  you can monitor the database if the transactions are there or use some tool like LinkedIn burrow to monitor your Kafka message group if you are integrating by using Kafka.

Conclusion is, instead to try monitor all the thing once it looks like creating specialist monitors for every step will be more assertive and simple to develop.